# How Can I Update Domains for Email Records In MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm running the following query to change the domains for all emails in my dev database but I keep getting this error for duplicate records, I believe there is records where the text before @ sign is the same. Can you please advise how do I modify my exiting query so I don't see this error?

```
UPDATE users SET email=REPLACE(email, SUBSTR(email,INSTR(email,'@')+1),'test.com');

Error:
    
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'username@test.com' for key 'email'
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should revise your database design. You probably have defined the email field as unique or even as the primary key. It isn't allowed to have the same email in more than one row. So, you are probably duplicating the same email when executing your query.

Comment: @RobertoC.Rodriguez-Hidalgo I did not create this database but looking at it, email is not a primary key, but is an index.

Comment: Check this link >>>> https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/ . You would find the cause right there.

Comment: How do you want the duplicates to be handled?  You need to explain the logic you want,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the domainname to the username and add your domain. so any email is unique.
you can easy split it wit **SUBSTRING_INDEX** like this.

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX("myuser@somedomain.com", "@", 1),'_',
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX("myuser@somedomain.com", "@", -1),'.','_'),
        '@testdomain.net') as newemail;

+--------------------------------------+
| newemail                             |
+--------------------------------------+
| myuser_somedomain_com@testdomain.net |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)

        
UPDATE users
    SET email = 
        CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, "@", 1),'_',
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, "@", -1),'.','_'),
        '@testdomain.net');
```

Comment: duplicates was an issue but I can tell you got the point I really don't care how duplicates are handles as long as I can change all emails. So thanks for this, it works.